Error creating form in dfm: Invalid stream format
While editing a TWebMemo, I switched the form over to the "View as Text" mode but when trying to get back to the form I receive an error stating:

Error Unit1.dfm: Invalid stream format.

When trying to save the file I am also met with the error:

Module 'Unit1' cannot be renamed because 'Form1' is viewed as text..

I tried closing the form but it needs to be saved first resulting in the same "Module Unit1 cannot be renamed because form Form1 is viewed as text" error.
Switching to form view via F12 also didn't work obviously.

I am using TMS WEB Core version V2.2 and RAD Studio 11

Sounds like a bug that you should report to TMS

Seems like you broke something in the DFM. Close the IDE, choose not to save changes, and then restart the IDE and load your project. If it's still broken, check the form back out from your version control system.

I'm able to switch between text view and form view without any issues in my TMS WEB Core projects. So I don't think it's a bug in TMS. I'm on the latest Delphi 12.1 and the latest TMS WEB Core 2.5.3.0. Maybe something got messed up in the DFM like Ken suggested.

@PufferFish What version of the IDE and TMS WEB Core are you using?
